# Why isn't privacy respected in an advanced society like Star Trek?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

In *Star Trek: TNG* (and probably other shows), anyone on the Enterprise can find anyone else by just asking the computer "Computer, locate XXX".

This seems like a major invasion of privacy. Even in our current human society, individual privacy is more protected than this. And Star Trek is supposed to take place in a far more "advanced" and "enlightened" society. So, why does this kind of invasion of privacy happen so often and no one complains about it?

Comment: you forget that the Enterprise is a hybred exploration, peace keeping, military vessel, and following that line of thought their would be very little privacy for the crew, as is the case in current Navel vessels.

Comment: Do modern Navel vessels require their crew to wear location-tracking tags? I don't know if this is the practice.

Comment: It's only an invasion of your privacy if you haven't consented to it, and something tells me setting foot aboard a Federation ship (especially in a professional occupation) is equivalent to giving consent. Also, given that they track the comm-badges, it seems it's just part of the job - which again, implies consent.

Comment: location tracking tags no, since we barely have tech that can do that, but you cant exactly "lock your room" in the military or navy, so the only privacy you would have on the entire ship is when your in the bathroom.

Comment: In a modern military vessel you can always find out where someone is, with or without tracking tags. Also remember that nobody is forcing you to join Starfleet.

Comment: @user486818 this was a perfectly good question, no need to delete it. Everyone else: why not post your _answers_ in the _answer_ box?

Comment: @KutuluMike, it was downvoted. I thought it was the typical unwelcomed "stupid" question on a strict forum like stack exchange. So, I deleted it and decided to ask it elsewhere. Thanks for reviving it.

Comment: @user486818 a downvote could mean any number of things, but it was only one. I wouldnt' sweat it.

Comment: @user486818 - Revived, but alas, it's a dupe of another question elsewhere on the site. You still get my upvote for asking a good question. Now go ask another :-)

Comment: @Jeff it's interesting to note that all of the mentions of privacy in that question are from Voyager. Also, I think that question's definitely related but not really a duplicate (IMO at least)

Comment: @Valorum I dunno if it's an exact duplicate. That question asks if there was any concept of privacy in ST. This one is asking why something that's an obvious invasion of privacy was allowed (e.g. if there were privacy protocols, why wasn't "you can't find me" one of them?)

Comment: @KutuluMike: The accepted answer to the linked question completely answers this question as well.

Comment: Well if someone really wanted privacy they can and do remove their com badge..

Comment: @KutuluMike - It's addressed that there are protocols (**JANEWAY:** *"There are protocols for observing privacy on this ship.*"). This question might survive if it was asking what those protocols actually are...

Comment: @Jeff everything in the linked question's answer is about accessing private data (reading mail, database access), except for one _speculation_ that perhaps the locate function is restricted to officers... I don't see how any of that answers this question.

Comment: @KutuluMike: the existence of privacy protocols and specific private databases, etc, implicitly answers the question - if privacy weren't respected, those protocols wouldn't exist.

Comment: I feel like you are intentionally ignoring what I'm writing but whatever.

Comment: A major flaw in your premise is that privacy is protected today. On the contrary, your cell phone and your web browsing habits leak far more privacy information, including your current location, to anyone who knows how to capture that data than anything ever portrayed in Star Trek. There is only the illusion of privacy nowadays. It's a minor thing in Star Trek to have your location easily discerned.